# Querying database of Windchill using SQL

Tags: oracle, ptc-windchill

Many vendors such as Microsoft with Sharepoint and Dynamics have made it impossible to access database tables directly in newer versions as they convert to Software as Service (SAS) offerings.

I am working with PTC Windchill and have developed extensive Oracle SQL Layer ETL processing. Is this a future proof practice within the context of this product line? Or in the future will I be required to work through some sort of DAL. If so, is there a recommended practice?

The information available from Windchill for Cloud appear vague and mostly suggesting to me virtualizion at the infrastructure layer, suggesting I would be able to query at the database layer for many years to come. Any confirmation, pointers or feedback would be  appreciated.

Comment: I don't know the PTC Windchill product but for SAAS offerings it's always the best to consume the Web (REST) API if there is one in place. 
A quick Google search brings me to this documentation page: http://support.ptc.com/help/windchill/whc/whc_en/index.html#page/Windchill_Help_Center/NewandChanged_REST_Odata.html
Don't know if you can get the desired data from this interface, but that would be the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Windchill offers extensive APIs for data access (and customization) in java. Starting from version 11.0, There are also some soap and rest web service for data access , but not for everything. It is always better to use API, they offer Data Abstraction Layer in a supported way. PTC would recommend that you refer to a consultant for this job.

But if you want to try:
There is a huge documentation about Windchill Customization, you can also create your own web services in java to access the data you want, if standard web services does not suffice. a starting point can be the Windchill help, and the javadoc located in the windchill server in this folder:
WINDCHILL_HOME/codebase/wt/clients/library/api/index.html
there are also some examples:
WINDCHILL_HOME/prog_examples
more documentation and appropriate training is available on https://support.ptc.com, only for registered customer users.